# Как лучше хранить страны и их города?

Tags: mysql, файлы

Разрабатываю продукт. Тут присутствуют страны и их города. И собственно вопрос - как лучше такое хранить? стран около 250 штук, а вот городов больше, при чем в разы. + ко всему требуется перевод каждой страны и города.

Один вариант это бд с двумя таблицами. Но вот как в этой ситуации бить с переводами? добавлять колонки под каждый язык - ну такое мне кажется.

Можно хранить в файлах, а при старте приложения считывать в память... но такое.

Что скажете по этому поводу?

Comment: А для каких целей справочники, что в них будет собственно кроме наименований. Как они будут использоваться, случайные выборки отдельных записей или получение полных списков. БД какого типа - с выделенным сервером БД или встроенная в приложение.

Comment: И да, как часто будет переключатся язык, требуется ли одновременно показывать названия на нескольких языках

Comment: @Mike показывается только один язык.Ну вот я думал что фронт (React) получает список всех стран и хранит у себя что бы не делать больше запросы. Ну и в месте где надо выбрать город уже будет делатся запрос на города по определенной стране и тоже сохранятся на фронте. Стран ~250 и это не сложно в принципе. А на счет переводов фронт сам будет разруливать какой перевод отдать. Ему главное что бы были поля с переводами.

Comment: Тут получается такая штука, что по правилам проектирования конечно должна быть таблица стран и к ней таблица названий, с id, языком и названием. Но это join при каждом запросе. Пока получаете название одного языка это вроде как не страшно. Если у вас отдельные колонки (что дико не удобно), либо колонка типа json и в ней буквально `{'RU':'США', 'EN':'USA'}` что явно удобнее (в mysql можно доставать как `field->>'$.RU'`). Но запись таблицы, если языков много, получается большая и опять получаете падение производительности при чтении.

Comment: Но если вы хотите отдать фронту сразу со всеми переводами, то выборка из нормализованной таблицы с join становится в разы более напряжной, чем считать целиком запись страны с полем json и прямо этот json отдать клиенту

Comment: @Mike в `json`-не я проблемы не вижу. Можно и так. Но вот как такое править - вопрос. Придется писать штуку в которой можно редактировать страны и их переводы. Если же говорить о первом вариант без `json` то можно все выгружать в память при старте приложения и брать уже оттуда.

Comment: Если у вас mysql то изменение одного имени что то вроде `update tab set name=json_replace(name, '$.RU', 'Ангола') ...`. В общем в нем есть функции для работы с json https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html И вытаскивать целиком на клиента все значения в поле для изменения одного не требуется. Так же тип json и функции для работы с ним есть в postgresql, ms sql, oracle

Answer (score 0):

Смотря сколько вариантов языка. Если 2-3, то в 2-х базах с колонками типа name_ru, name_en... Так же и города.
Если локализаций намного больше - выносить в отдельные БД. Но ври любом раскладе из фа читаться будет значительнее медленнее.

Кстати, существует уже много примеров, может взять уже готовую БД и не изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Может и есть готовые. я не в курсе. Знаю что есть готовые сборники стран и городов.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно хранить это в трех таблицах:

Таблица Country:

```
id,
country_name,
lang_id
```

Таблица Cities:

```
id,
cities_name,
lang_id,
country_id
```

Таблица Language:

```
id,
language_name
```

Пример:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME,
       CITIES_NAME,
       LANGUAGE_NAME
  FROM COUNTRY
    LEFT JOIN CITIES
      ON COUNTRY.ID = CITIES.COUNTRY_ID
    LEFT JOIN LANGUAGE
      ON LANGUAGE.ID = COUNTRY.LANG_ID
  WHERE LANGUAGE_NAME IN ('EN'); --EN, RU, UK
```

Результат:

[image]

Comment: вот так делать точно нельзя. Добавляем запись USA id 1. Язык английский. Надо теперь добавить русское название. Приходится заводить отдельную запись страны США. И у нее id будет уже 2. А теперь нам надо воспользоваться этим справочником и где то указать страну и какой id нам брать 1 или 2 и как при переключении языка интерфейса понять, что везде где использовались USA надо показывать  США ?

Comment: @Mike, дополнил ответ, я думаю запрос говорит сам за себя

Comment: Запрос ни о чем не говорит. Выведите пожалуйста английское название страны и русские названия городов в ней. Или хотя бы все названия одной и той же страны (например страны с id=1)

Comment: так здесь прикол не в том чтоб хранить название страны с ее переводами под одним id

Comment: `английское название страны и русские названия городов в ней` зачем так вообще делать

Comment: А в чем тогда прикол ? Самая распространенная ситуация: я захожу в программу, по умолчанию стоит английский интерфейс. я завожу некие данные, да хоть указываю свою страну проживания в анкете. сохраняю. разумеется в БД сохраняется ее id. И после этого я решаю, что меня не устраивает английский интерфейс и я переключаю язык на русский. И очевидно, что я хочу видеть в анкете уже русское название страны. На самом деле в проектировании БД есть одно непреложное правило: сущность, которая в реальной жизни одна, должна быть представлена ровно одной записью (в основной таблице) и иметь единственный id.

Comment: _английское название страны и русские названия городов в ней зачем так вообще делать_. Да очень просто, вы переведите за раз названия всех городов России. Вы скорее всего получите некий справочник извне, запишите русские названия и все. Для каких то городов добавите переводы. А по остальным должно действовать правило - если нет перевода на требуемом языке берем перевод на другом

Comment: @Mike, согласен